# FrameLayout buttons overlap, and can't be 'touched. - what's right way to access?

Tags: android

I'm using a FrameLayout and have two buttons on it, button A and button B (in addition to some other widgets).  A is directly on top of B, overlapping completely.

In onCreate, I do a check and if A is not needed, I set it to invisible.  Later in the app it may become visible again so I don't want to remove it completely.

When button B is pressed, it doesn't respond.  I think button A is stopping the press even though it's invisible.  Other buttons do respond so this is why I think this.

Is there a common way to make it so B accepts touches?  Do I have to remove A?  I don't really want to remove A as I have a relative layout in the frame layout and other controls depend on A for positioning.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish with two buttons directly on top of each other?

Comment: Depending on what the user does, they will need one of the two buttons to be shown.  I could make one button and change the properties of it, but it wouldn't help me understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it would make a lot more sense to have a single button who's properties vary based on configuration.  However, if you really want to have two, you could try a couple of things:

Set the invisible button to not be focusable or touchable.
Set the button to Gone, not invisible.  This might mess up the layout though, since this basically says not to consider the button when doing the layout.

Comment: Even when sent to GONE, button B still doesn't respond to touch events...I'll keep trying =)

Comment: Maybe I should just create/remove buttons on the fly?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Just change the text and onClick method of the button based on which behavior you want.